# c++ sub get all exe files in current directory

Tags: c++

c++ sub get all exe files in current directory

I'm trying to get all the `.exe` files in current directory.

but I have some error, can someone correct me.

edit :

i have this 2 error :

1/ IntelliSense: argument of type "WIN32_FIND_DATA *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA"

2/ IntelliSense: argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

```
void ml() 
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA Finde;

HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFileA("*.exe", &Finde);

if(strcmp(Finde.cFileName,"test.exe") != 0 )
{
    strong(Finde.cFileName);
}
while(FindNextFileA(hFind,&Finde))
{
    if(FindFileData.cFileName,"test.exe") 
    {
         strong(Finde.cFileName);
    }

}

FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
1.  You need to check that hFind is valid
2.  Your 'if' inside the loop is missing strcmp

Comment: i have this 2 error
1/ IntelliSense: argument of type "WIN32_FIND_DATA *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA" 
2/ IntelliSense: argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Comment: Because your project is set to unicode, and you're using the default struct.   Add an  'A' to the type   WIN32_FIND_DATAA